# If you introduce a 3rd group into O- chlorotoluene, which position will the 3rd group prefer?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I read that Cl is ring deactivating group even if it is O,P- directing. Which group among the methyl and chloro controls the orientation of the 3rd substituent. What are the products formed?

Comment: It depends on many things.

Answer (score 3):

The nitration of *o*-chlorotoluene gives all four possible isomers according to Wibaut [[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/recl.19130321002)].

#### Reference

1. Wibaut, J. P. Recherches Quantitatives Sur La Nitration Des Chlorotoluènes. *Recueil des Travaux Chimiques des Pays-Bas et de la Belgique* **1913**, 32 (10), 244–320. https://doi.org/10.1002/recl.19130321002.