# Confusion about orienting effects in o-chlorotoluene

Tags: aromatic-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

I'm confused about where the next substituent in the electrophilic substitution of o-chlorotoluene will land. My question comes on the background of having 3 different sources of information that say different things. 
The first one is my teacher: she taught us that at the nitration of ortho-chlorotoluene, the $\ce{NO2}$ group will be placed in the 4 position, giving 2-chloro-4-nitro-toluene. This seems reasonable, but even more reasonable seems the second source. That is [this](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/benzrx2.htm) website, which shows that the product will be 2-chloro-5-nitrotoluene (3<sup>rd</sup> image, example 2).
The 3<sup>rd</sup> source is completely confusing, giving little citation as I was not able to find the material cited online. I'm talking about a question on this website [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88041/if-you-introduce-a-3rd-group-into-o-chlorotoluene-which-position-will-the-3rd), but I am not sure if I can trust it, that is the reason why I'm adding another question.

So, can someone please explain me what is the actual product?

Comment: As I answered on the question you cited, when the experiment was carried out a mixture was obtained. The directing effects of Me and Cl are of similar magnitude so neither prevails, hence a mixture. If you want further discussion I suggest you direct your teacher to the original literature reference. Theory is all very well, but there is no substitute for the experience of someone who has run the reaction.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now, this also explains why the theory in the sources varies.

Comment: Also, do you have a link to the material you cited in that question? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @StefanOctavian I added the URL to the [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88041/if-you-introduce-a-3rd-group-into-o-chlorotoluene-which-position-will-the-3rd), but it looks like it's a 80-page article written in French(?). Good luck:)

Comment: In such cases, I always remain cautious about how people really numbered the positions around the benzene ring, because if you consider that the methyl group of toluene is on position 1 (because toluene is the parent), that is very different with considering that the halogen atom is on position 1 (because halogen has priority). And remember that the IUPAC rules have not always existed!